# What do these iptable rules mean?

Tags: iptables, network-bridge, routing, port-forwarding

These:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm new to iptables and the FORWARD, POSTROUTING  AND PREROUTING, MASQUERADE rules are all so completely indecipherable to me.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

A packet destined to go out via the tun0 interface will be nat (Network Address Translation)'d to the tun0 IP address.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

A packet arriving on the tun0 interface and destined for the wlan0 interface will be accepted if this session is already in the connection tracking table. Yes, you can assume the reverse of the outgoing nat occurs here, translating back to the original wlan0 ip address.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

A packet arriving on the wlan0 interface and destined for the tun0 interface is unconditionally allowed.

Note that these type of rules in the FORWARD chain assume a default policy of DROP, because otherwise they are not required. The entire context of the iptables rule set would be required to know for certain.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. I think I for now can comprehend at least 70% of it even though I have no foundation in iptables.